# Creating a Windows screensaver on a single display

Tags: c++, windows

I am writing an application to load a screen-saver on a single, individual, display whilst being able to work on the other monitors. Will I have to create my own screen-savers (Would I writ them in OpenGL, D3D, D2D or Windows API?) or would it be possible to use existing screen-savers and set the parameters I need?

I know applications can 'preview' a screensaver at full-screen and not close until you close the application, would that be possible in this situation? As I don't see much point re-inventing the wheel, just the car on top of those wheels.

EDIT: found the application mentioned previous
http://www.dual-monitor.biz/screen-saver-on-second-monitor-only/

> The Screen Saver running in the window works by displaying preview of the screen saver. Many Screen Savers have live preview feature enabled for the screen saver, The live preview in turn means that the screen saver will run normally in the window as it would run in full screen mode.

The program is written in C++ using Windows API

Comment: Screensavers under Windows switch to an alternate desktop display, so there's no possible way to interact with the normal desktop while it's up.

Comment: @Mark Ransom
http://www.dual-monitor.biz/screen-saver-on-second-monitor-only/

Comment: By having the screen saver show itself in preview mode it's no longer technically a screen saver. If your code has the preview capability you can do the same thing.

Comment: I have programmed a way of monitoring inactivity and if that monitor has been interacted with by the mouse. I just want to show screen-savers that already exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a borderless form covering the monitor in question, then [run the screensaver](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/182383) with `/p <form.HWnd>` to run it as a child of that window.

Comment: Thank you for the information, might seem a silly question, but how would I include a screen-saver and declare it?

Comment: @BuiltonSin: Screen savers are just EXE files with a different extension.  You simply use `Process.Start()`.